# Select values above and below limit with same query?

Tags: sql

I have a table witch hold random numbers - for example (1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10).
Is it possible to select the sum of numbers that are below 5 and the sum of numbers that are above 5 within one query?

Something like:

```
SELECT sum(numbers_below_five), sum(numbers_above_five) from numbers
```

If it is possible then is there point in doing so or would two queries faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement for this:

```
SELECT
    SUM (CASE WHEN n > 5 THEN n ELSE 0 END) as SumGreaterThanFive,
    SUM (CASE WHEN n <= 5 THEN n ELSE 0 END) as SumLessThanFive
FROM myTable
```

Assuming that accessing your RDBMS requires a network roundtrip, a single query should be faster than two queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(case when num_column < 5 then num_column end) as numbers_below_five,
       sum(case when num_column > 5 then num_column end) as numbers_above_five
from numbers
```